# Executar comando do console e ler o retorno em PHP

Tags: php, linux, terminal

No linux se eu fizer o comando `df -h` no terminal ele me retorna as partições, tamanho etc ... como mostro abaixo:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda3        25G  6.4G   17G  28% /
/dev/sda5        70G  2.9G   64G   5% /var
/dev/sda1       190M   29M  147M  17% /boot
/dev/sde1       394G  340G   34G  92% /u
```

É possível pegar esse resultado e trazer para o php?

Exemplo, grava-los em variáveis para eu poder exibir em um painel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O `shell_exec()` já executa e retorna a saída do comando como *string*:

```
<?php
   $output = shell_exec('df -h');
   echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
?>
```

Lembre-se que a conta de usuário que estiver executando o PHP precisa ter permissão para a execução.

Comment: Certo, mais consigo setar qual servidor eu quero, exemplo:  como faria se fosse 3 servidores destintos ?

Comment: Cada PHP vai pegar do seu próprio servidor. Ele executa como se fosse um usuário.

Comment: Entendi, Obrigado ! já validei a sua resposta, Obrigado !

Comment: @otaciojb se precisar executar remoto, teria que usar alguma coisa como um ssh. Dá pra fazer com a mesma idéia, mas a complexidade do comando aumenta um pouco.

Comment: é porque tenho 5 servidores e gostaria de criar um painel de monitoramento deles,um tela simples que mostre esses dados. Vou estudar a questão do ssh como você disse, Obrigado !

Comment: Pense num script shell neles que faça um curl pro seu PHP com os dados, pode ser bem mais simples. Pouquissimas linhas, e com o CURL você pode fazer o resultado do comando dar um GET num PHP central do painel. Ai nao precisa instalar nada. Só por no crontab,

Comment: Blza, Obrigado !